# VS2010 don't publish particular folders/files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

I saw this question but it's related to VS2008 so I thought maybe things have changed:
[Don't publish particular folder in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778872/dont-publish-particular-folder-in-asp-net)

Anyway the question is, when I publish my ASP.net website it creates the publish folder and publishes files such as `web.config`and the `images/` directory.  The web.config on the live server has different configuration, and the images don't need to be uploaded again.

Can I make it not publish specific files/folders as it would make my upload process a lot faster and safer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Simply change `Build Action` property of your file to `None`

Comment: Thanks, I've uploaded a screenshot, where should this property be found?

Comment: I have another category `Advanced`. I'm trying to find out how to enable it in your VS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498245/how-to-set-build-action-on-a-file-advanced-properties-not-displayed-in-properti :( Does this mean it's not possible?

Comment: I created sample `Web Site` project. Unfortunately file properties window looks the same as in your screenshot. Maybe you can convert your project to `Web Application`?

Comment: I think it's not possible. Probably because `Web Site` project type doesn't contain `*.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution must contain a project file (.csproj). You get this if you work with Web Application projects instead of Web Site projects. You can also convert you Web Site project to the Web Application project. Personally I never work with Web Site projects, they have management issues (like the one we are discussing about) and offer little support for additional projects, like Console App project or Class Library projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I use a web site project, I simply cut & paste the massive images folder to a parent folder outside of the project before publishing. Then, I cut & paste the folder back into the project folder after publishing completes. It only takes a few seconds to do this.